# Fabric git pushing to wrong ip address

Tags: python, git, fabric

I'm working on win7 and trying to use fabric to push changes to an ubuntu 16.04 VPS. So far I have:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'test': ['localhost'],
    'dev': ['user@dev.example.com'],
    'production': ['deploy@xxx.xx.xx.xx']
}

@roles('production')
    def dir():
        env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
        local("pip freeze > requirements.txt")
        local("git add . --all && git commit -m 'fab'")
        local("git push myproject master")
        run('pwd')
        ...
```

When I run this the output is:

```
$ fab dir
[deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx] Executing task 'dir'
[localhost] local: pip freeze > requirements.txt
[localhost] local: git add . --all && git commit -m 'fab'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .idea/workspace.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .idea/workspace.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
256de92] 'fab'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .idea/workspace.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 3 files changed, 10 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
[localhost] local: git push example master
debug1: Connecting to 198.91.88.101 [198.91.88.101] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 198.91.88.101 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 198.91.88.101 port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 128) while executing 'git push example master'
```

So fabric is trying to push to the wrong target ip address (this was an old vps address . I no longer have it.) I got rid of the VPS but saved the public and private key and uploaded the pub key to my new vps at a new ip address

The problem is I'm not sure where the old target address is being set. Is this a git issue. How do I redirect fabric to push to  @roles('production')

When I look in my .ssh/known_hosts I see 198.91.88.101. So I'm wondering if that is involved in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the git remote configuration. Verify with `git remote --verbose`.

Comment: $ git remote --verbose
example     ssh://deploy@198.91.88.101/~/example (fetch)
example     ssh://deploy@198.91.88.101/~/example (push)